# What is this critter

Tags: species-identification

I found this "thing" crawling across my drive way. Never seen anything like it and no one I know can identify it.

Was about 4 to 5 inches long and 1/4 wide. It move some what like a worm in that segments of it's body seemed to move to propel itself forward very slowly.

I have a video as well if that would help but it is one my cell phone. I live near Gettysburg PA.

[image]

Comment: Possibly some kind of bagworm moth, or clothes moth. Not sure if those are the same or different..

Comment: Upload your video on ezgif.com, convert it to a gif < 2mb in size, and add it to your post :)